# Did 2011 election jump from nomination to election before the deadline

Tags: support, moderation, election

Just recently (yesterday?) I thought there were ~3 days remaining for nominations. Am I right? If so, why?

Comment: I think you are wrong, you may have misread somewhere. If you wanted to nominate yourself, I'm sure an exception can be made...

Comment: i saw that the red text link on the main page was gone this morning, but when i hit 'meta', the message here said nominations were still open for 9 hours.

Comment: @JustJeff, I watched it through 8am Central time seeing whom else would jump in at the last moment and then went to sleep, it was not at 9 hours then. It may have been cached in your browser.

Comment: @Joby Taffey I'm not going to nominate myself. I'm happy with who ended up running.

Comment: i wanted to nominate *others*. fortunately, for the most part they nominated themselves.

Comment: @JustJeff, Ouch, guess you did not like the first three. Yes, the went to people nominating themselves. At one point you could nominate someone else, but they then needed to edit in their acceptance. It was messy, this method makes more sense.

Comment: @Kortuk - i meant 'other' only as in 'other than myself' - not a statement about regime change!

Comment: @JustJeff, I saw a chance to give some friendly ribbing, had to take it.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't have been.  The nomination phase started on Tuesday, April 26th at 20:00 UTC.  This phase lasts a week.  Today is a week later, Tuesday, and 20:00 UTC has already passed.

(These dates are available in the left sidebar on the election page.)

Comment: I also saw the clock tick as expected.